# AudioManager getVolume custom method

Tags: android, audio, volume

My getVolume() method is always returning me 1.0. I have muted my phone, changed the volume but I am getting 1f anytime when I call my method. Am I missing something?

```
btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
      float volume = getVolume();
      Log.i("inf", "Volume: " + volume);
      soundPlayID = soundPool.play(my_sound, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
   }
});

private float getVolume(){
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float actualVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float maxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

    return volume;
}
```

Console:

> Volume: 1.0
>
> Volume: 1.0
>
> Volume: 1.0
>
> Volume: 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maxVolume here appears to be the SAME as the volume. The calls are identical, and so you will always get 1.0 as a result.

You need to call:

```
audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

and then you should see more interesting results.